# UINavigationBar Large Title Ghosting

Tags: ios, animation, uinavigationbar, large-title

When tapping the back button in my `UINavigationBar` the small title becomes a large title but with a strange ghosting effect during the animation.

Has anyone seen this before and/or know how to correct it?

[image: UINavigationBarGhosting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, the ghosting will happen when you only set appearance attributes for the `normal` control state:

```swift
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.barButtonBody()], for: UIControl.State.normal)
```

To prevent the ghosting, you also need to set it for the `highlighted` state:

```swift
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.barButtonBody()], for: UIControl.State.highlighted)
```